# Как написать команду с символом \

Tags: python

```
import pyautogui


pyautogui.press('.\hashcat.exe -m 13000 -a 3')
```

Использую данную команду чтобы вывести этот текст её в терминале windows 10, но проблемы с выводом знака \

Как можно его вывести?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте либо raw-строки: `r'.\hashcat.exe -m 13000 -a 3'`. Либо экранируйте символы обратным слешем в обычной строке `'.\\hashcat.exe -m 13000 -a 3'`.